# Keep image position when shrinking screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to implement responsiveness to this screen but I'm having trouble keeping things in place. When I'm in desktop mode, the laptop image stays where it should be, in the center of the lines, on top of the square. But I just shrink the screen, and the image of the lines meets the edge of the screen and shrinks out of sync with the laptop image. Is there any way I can synchronize this downsizing?

[image]

[image]

This is my page:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import logo from '../assets/logomarca-branco.png'
import wave from '../assets/svg/wave.svg'
import Lines from '../components/Lines'
import Computer from '../components/Computer'
import AutoWrite from '../components/AutoWrite'
import MobileNavbar from '../components/MobileNavbar'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  console.log(wave);

  return (
    <div>
      <section className='bg-[#352575] w-full h-screen relative'>
        <Navbar logo={logo}>
          <span>Home</span>
          <span>Sobre</span>
          <span>Serviços</span>
          <span>Portifólio</span>
          <span>Contato</span>
        </Navbar>
        <MobileNavbar logo={logo}></MobileNavbar>
        <div style={{ height: 'calc(100% - 56px)' }} className="relative">
          <div className='inline-block ml-16 mt-32'>
            <AutoWrite></AutoWrite>
          </div>
          <Computer></Computer>
          <Lines></Lines>
          <img src={wave.src} alt="wave" className='absolute bottom-0' />
        </div>
      </section>
      <section className='bg-[#F3F4F5] w-full h-screen relative'></section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

This is the computer container:

```
import computer from '../assets/svg/computer.svg'
import computerFloor from '../assets/svg/computer-floor.svg'


export default function Computer() {
    return (
        <>
            <img src={computer.src} alt="computer" className='absolute z-10 right-8 bottom-20' />
            <img src={computerFloor.src} alt="computerFloor" className='absolute z-0 right-8 bottom-20 opacity-50' />
        </>
    )
}
```

This is the lines container:

```
import lineBright from '../assets/svg/lines-bright.svg'
import linesClean from '../assets/svg/lines-clean.svg'

export default function Lines() {
    return (
        <div className='w-min h-min'>
            <img src={lineBright.src} alt="lineBright" className='absolute right-0 bottom-0 opacity-40' />
            <img src={linesClean.src} alt="lineClean" className='absolute right-8 bottom-0 opacity-40' />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `background-position-x` with the desired horizontal placement of the lines background.

For example:

```
.w-min img{
 background-position-x: 25%;
}
```

...if the lines background would be a part of the CSS,

but in your case you'd need `left` (or right), like so:

```
.w-min{
 left: 25%;
 position: relative;
}
```